# Double to simple integral inequality

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions. Prove that exists $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
>
> $$\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f(x)g(y)}{x+y}dxdy\leq c\int_0^{\infty}f(x)g(x)\,dx$$

I have no idea how to proceed, can you give me some advice?